# Blank output using Ruby twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

When I execute there is no error, no output either. This is all the code in the file.

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ""
    config.consumer_secret = ""
    config.access_token = ""
    config.access_token_secret = ""
end

client.home_timeline
```

When I use this example it works, so I assume I have something right:

```
topics = ["coffee", "tea"]
client.filter(:track => topics.join(",")) do |object|
    puts object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
end
```

This is the only example I can get working, all others with produce no output. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "$client" that will make it global. May work this way.

```
$client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ""
    config.consumer_secret = ""
    config.access_token = ""
    config.access_token_secret = ""
end

$client.home_timeline
```